# Does the word "raytracer" exist?

Tags: orthography, is-it-a-word, programming, spacing

If not, is it well readable anyway?

["Ray tracer"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing) seems to be used more frequently but this is not my question.

An example sentence could be:

> A **raytracer** is a computer program that uses an algorithm where light rays are traced back to their origin to create realistic 2D images from 3D scenes.

Comment: It would help if you included a definition and example of it.

Comment: I believe POV-Ray, which has been around since 1989, has always called itself "raytracer", one word. This sort of wavering between two-word, hyphenated-word and single-word forms is normal in the first generation after a new term is introduced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly wouldn't be misunderstood if you used *raytrace*, *raytracer*, or *raytracing* in your writing.

If you peruse the [comp.graphics.raytracing](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/comp.graphics.raytracing) newsgroup, you'll see that it's pretty common to write the terms as *closed compounds* (one word, unhyphenated).

Comment: Interesting fact. Nevertheless, I am not sure whether the word exists. I did not find it in any dictionaries.

Comment: @JuliusKunze: Words exist even if they're not (yet) in the dictionary.

Comment: @JuliusKunze: like Hugo and StoneyB said, and it's been around since at least 1989. If anyone's got a 1990 1st edition copy of Foley, van Dam, Feiner, Hughes, they might check if they use the term.